# Raphael-JS: Rect with one round corner

Tags: javascript, raphael

```
paper.rect(0, 0, settings.width, settings.height, settings.radius);
```

Creates a nice rectangle with rounded corners. Is it possible to create a rectangle with just one round corner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rounded corners feature maps directly on to the underlying SVG [`rx`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElementRXAttribute) and [`ry`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElementRYAttribute) attributes, they apply to whole rectangles and so there's no possibility of just setting it on a single corner.

[This blog post](http://my.opera.com/lugansk/blog/2008/07/20/rounded-corners-in-svg-making-not-all-corners-round) discusses an approach in SVG of basically covering up the corners you don't want rounded.  Although his examples appear to be offline now, the approach should be fairly easy to reverse engineer into SVG.

An alternative approach would be to use [a path](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#path) instead of a rectangle object and draw the whole outline yourself.  The syntax is a little obscure but is easy enough once you understand what's going on.  Try [Jakob Jenkov's SVG Path tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html) for an introduction.

Answer (score 26):

If you use Raphael JS:

```
Raphael.fn.roundedRectangle = function (x, y, w, h, r1, r2, r3, r4){
  var array = [];
  array = array.concat(["M",x,r1+y, "Q",x,y, x+r1,y]); //A
  array = array.concat(["L",x+w-r2,y, "Q",x+w,y, x+w,y+r2]); //B
  array = array.concat(["L",x+w,y+h-r3, "Q",x+w,y+h, x+w-r3,y+h]); //C
  array = array.concat(["L",x+r4,y+h, "Q",x,y+h, x,y+h-r4, "Z"]); //D

  return this.path(array);
};
```

To have a rectangle with only the upper-right corner rounded

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas", 840, 480);
paper.roundedRectangle(10, 10, 80, 80, 0, 20, 0, 0);
```

Source and online example: http://www.remy-mellet.com/blog/179-draw-rectangle-with-123-or-4-rounded-corner/

Comment: This works great for static rounded rectangles, but doesn't work if you need to use the Raphael animate method, unfortunately. Would love to see a version that is animate-able.

Comment: @nickb Why wouldn't it work with animate? It's just a path, yes? I wonder what the hangup is?

Answer (score 2):

Very old question, here's a better path. I converted it to relative coordinates, which should be better at animations...

```
Raphael.fn.roundedRectangle = function (x, y, w, h, r1, r2, r3, r4){
  var array = [];
  array = array.concat(["M",x+r1,y]);
  array = array.concat(['l',w-r1-r2,0]);//T
  array = array.concat(["q",r2,0, r2,r2]); //TR
  array = array.concat(['l',0,h-r3-r2]);//R
  array = array.concat(["q",0,r3, -r3,r3]); //BR
  array = array.concat(['l',-w+r4+r3,0]);//B
  array = array.concat(["q",-r4,0, -r4,-r4]); //BL
  array = array.concat(['l',0,-h+r4+r1]);//L
  array = array.concat(["q",0,-r1, r1,-r1]); //TL
  array = array.concat(["z"]); //end

  return this.path(array);
};
```